# Datagrid ScrollBar WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to add a scrollbar in within my Datagrid but it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

```
<Grid x:Name="DisplayClient" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,135,10,-132">
    <Expander Header="Client" IsExpanded="{Binding IsResultOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
         <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientList}">
        </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: why are you not relying on scrollbar that is within datagrid ?

Comment: I tried it too but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The scrollbar isn't showing

Comment: that's another problem ...post more code ..

Comment: The scroll bar will only show if the content inside the DataGrid exceeds its bounds. Try inserting 100 rows and the scroll bar should display.

Comment: Give a fixed height for the Grid and the date exceeds the fixed height will show up the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly this trouble. I suggest you make the datagrid and/or the scrollviewer have a maxheight. When the datagrid reaches this maxheight the scrollviewer should kick in.

```
<Grid x:Name="DisplayClient" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,135,10,-132">
    <Expander Header="Client" IsExpanded="{Binding IsResultOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight=400>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" MaxHeight="400" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientList}">
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```